# virtualenv not found in path

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04

For some reason virtualenv is not in my path after installing with pip3. I have a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04.

```
sudo apt-get install pip3
pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv # command not found!!!
```

edit: I also installed jupyter notebook with pip3 and its not in the path either.

Comment: The installer probably updated your `PATH` setting but you didn't source nor re-login. If the problem persist after logging out and logging in, you may need to manually update `PATH`.

Comment: I re-logged but it didn't do anything. Where does it install the virtualenv executable? pip3 show virtual-env lists it in ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ - should I add that entire dir to $PATH?

Comment: It looks like you installed `vitualenv` as regular user. Check your home directory. It should be in `$HOME/bin`.

Comment: There is no ~/bin directory.

Answer (score 3):

Python executables are placed in ~/.local/bin/ on Ubuntu 16.04.
This location is not in $PATH so edit your .bashrc to append it there.

```
# .bashrc file
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

This is **Ubuntu only** (didn't check other distros)

**TL;DR** (if you used pip to install pkg) run following command

```
$ source ~/.profile
```

---

If you examine `.profile` there is a script looks like following.
(18 version. 16 version has something different)

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

which means everything under `~/.local/bin` will be added to PATH.
So, if you used pip to install pkg and try to run from prompt. As long as pip created file under the folder it will let you run commands without full path.
You can restart the session too. Whichever you feel comfortable with.